# Trying to add new line characters while using JSF h:outputText and Managed Beans

Tags: jsf, text, javabeans, managed-bean

I have a h:outputText here

```
<h:outputText id="properties" value="#myBean.output}" />
```

Then I have a button that calls a function that updates the value in "output" which is a String that holds essentially a text document in it (That being multiple lines)

```
<h:panelGrid columns="2" >
    <p:outputLabel value="Display Output."/>
    <p:commandButton value="submit" action="#{myBean.updateOutput}">
        <f:ajax render="properties" />
    </p:commandButton>                  
</h:panelGrid>
```

However, I want it to have \n or some equivalent in output.

This is an example of what I would return:

```
Line1\nLine2\nLine3
```

However this just prints to the screen like this:

```
Text1 Text2 Text3
```

Changing it to br/ it doesn't do anything but cause it to put the literal text br/ instead of the white spaces above.

I am new to JSF and I just can't figure it out.  I did search for an answer but none worked for me.  I would really appreciate some help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Set `escape` attribute on `h:outputText` to `false`.

> Escape is  Flag indicating that characters that are sensitive in HTML and
>   XML markup must be escaped. This flag is set to "true" by default.

Comment: in addition, `escape="false"` will not work with \n, but will work with `<br/>`.